# Return component data using switch and Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to do a switch inside a function and i'm use react hooks.
The switch works fine but i cannot return a component..why?
The idea is that as I go through the array i will load the corresponding component whit all his data at that moment.

```
export default function Content({content}) {

const [contentBooks, setContentBooks] = useState(null);
const [contentFilms, setContentFilms] = useState(null);

async function data() {

    return await Promise.all(content.map(element => element.content).map(async item => {
        if (item.type == 'DETAIL') {
            switch (item.type) {
                case 'BOOKS':
                    const bookstype = await axios.get(`url`)
                    setContentBooks(bookstype)
                    return <Componen1 info={contentBooks} // --> not work
                case 'FILMS':
                    const filmstype = await axios.get(``)
                    setContentFilms(filmstype)
                    return <Componen2 info={contentFilms} // --> not work

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }))
  }

 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
       const result = await data()
  };

   fetchData();
}, [content]); 



return (
   <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>
   )
```

}

Comment: you're returning a `<React.Fragment/>` with no content, so on the page you shouldn't see any content. i haven't seen this style before, are you trying to lazy-load the books and films components?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need this resource: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-pass-props-to-component/

I don't think that is the correct way of calling a component in react

Answer (score 0):

there is alot wrong with this. first your components have no closing tag not sure how this even compiles.

```js
<Componen2 info={contentFilms}/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

next you are going an extremely round about way of calling the component.
load it once, not in the useeffect.